# Property 'includes' does not exist when building Angular library

Tags: angular, npm, build, lib

I am currently trying to compile my Angular library but when I run

```
npm build:lib
```

there is always an error:

> Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

The develop server is running without any problem (`ng serve`). So does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem.

This it the content of my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look on this https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/931#issuecomment-244001423

Comment: I took the liberty to format your code and error message. Please use code environments (indented by four spaces or wrapped in backticks) for code and either code or quotation environments (with a leading >) to format errors.

Comment: The Lib entry is already on es2017 and so I do not know how to solve.